# Create specific time range in react native

Tags: typescript, react-native, date, datetime

I am new with react native and I want to display a component with a specific time range only.
This is what i did so far

```
var timerange = new Date()
return(
  <View>
  {timerange.getHour() === 8}
   <Text>display</Text>
  </View>
)
```

So, if you can see that I display the text in exactly 8 o'clock. I want it to be precisely display at 8 to 16.
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an inline conditional as follows.

```js
var current = new Date()

return (
    {(current.getHours() >= 8 && current.getHours() <= 16) && <Text>It is between 8 and 16 o`clock</Text>}
)
```

Comment: I understand now, I just literally missed a basic logic and thought something far more complex. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad I could help :)